# Dynamic model name on the JSON value from the Backend

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angular-directive

I have a Json from backend like this:

```
var infoArray = [
        {
            "field" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "Name",
            "modelName" : "userName"
        },{
            "field" : "date",
            "placeholder" : "DOB",
            "modelName" : "userDob" 
        },{
            "field" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "Location",
            "modelName" : "userLocation"
        }
    ];
```

> It's already set that there can be at most 10 text fields and 4 date
>   fields i can get.

**Since ModelName is coming from backend so i am trying to put that in the simple ng-repeat but that seems not working**
[Here is Plnkr Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/vLYcr6qpwYkhFDNIOYOE?p=preview)

> Indeed i found one solution by myself and the code seems to be bulky
>   for that.

[Here is plnkr Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ybf19miBy4lGVeJ5h90R?p=preview)

> And one more thing i have to consider is that i have to use the modelName to get the values from the user and then sent it back.

Could anyone please suggest the optimized solution or modification over my code.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you tried is almost correct. just need to remove the curly brackets in `ng-model`

```
 <div ng-repeat="info in infoArray">
       <input type="{{info.field}}" placeholder="{{info.placeholder}}" ng-model="info.modelName" ng-init="callFunc(info)" /> 
 </div>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VQvPHyCrIedQbxhlPwnH?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I tried that! But the thing is that on the basis of the modelName i have to take user inputs and again sent the json back![link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uq3zW6ApnfvcgBlZUfd7?p=preview)  I am able to achieve that with my bulky solution!

Comment: but the changes you done via inputs will affect to the main array. console the main array on submit click and check

Comment: Yes ! It's Working fine .Thanks :)

Comment: @Niraj Sazzie no prob. make sure to check as right answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following manner:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.answers={};
  $scope.infoArray = [
        {
            "field" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "Name",
            "modelName" : "userName"
        },{
            "field" : "date",
            "placeholder" : "DOB",
            "modelName" : "userDob"
        },{
            "field" : "text",
            "placeholder" : "Location",
            "modelName" : "userLocation"
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.print=function(){
      console.log(answers);
    }

    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="info in infoArray">
    
       <input type="{{info.field}}" placeholder="{{info.placeholder}}" ng-model="answers[info.modelName]"/> 
   </div> 
   <button ng-click="print()">Print</button>
   {{answers.userName}}
   {{answers.userDob}}
   {{answers.userLocation}}
   
  </body>

</html>
```

> Remove curly braces from ng-model and in your javascript file create a new object as in my example i have created an ***answers*** object. and in the ng-model use in this way : `

```
   <input type="{{info.field}}" placeholder="{{info.placeholder}}" ng-model="answers[info.modelName]"/>
```

`
Now , if you want to access model values then you can do in this way:

```
   {{answers.userName}}
   {{answers.userDob}}
   {{answers.userLocation}}
```

Hope , this solves your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You understand the way i am trying to achieve from code. But it's saying **Error: answers is not defined** I figured out that `console.log($scope.answers)` Thanks :)